# Error al tratar de recorrer un JSON en react

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, reactjs

Estoy desarrollando una página web usando el Stack Mern, la parte del Backend ya está lista y probada usando Postman, y en este momento estoy desarrollando el frontend, pero en este punto quiero traer datos en formato JSON y pasarlos en una tabla, pero me está generando el siguiente error **Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '_id' of undefined** en react. Al ver la consola el JSON que me está regresando es el siguiente

```
[
    {
        "Estado": 1,
        "_id": "5dfbeec1f87e0e3030b38143",
        "Nombre_Empresa": "INNOVA ID TECHNOLOGY",
        "Fecha_Creacion": "2019-12-19T21:42:25.346Z"
    },
    {
        "Estado": 1,
        "_id": "5dfbfbd11ba6632d74036579",
        "Nombre_Empresa": "Coca-Cola Company",
        "Fecha_Creacion": "2019-12-19T22:38:09.139Z"
    },
    {
        "Estado": 1,
        "_id": "5dfbfc231ba6632d7403657a",
        "Nombre_Empresa": "Google Inc",
        "Fecha_Creacion": "2019-12-19T22:39:31.299Z"
    }
]
```

Que es exactemente el JSON esperado como respuesta desde el backend. El código que me está generando el problema es el siguiente

```
if(response && response.length !== 0){// El request no ha devuelto un arreglo vacio
                let dt = response;
                console.log(dt);

                dt.map((el,i)=>{
                    let filterProperties = [];//Propiedades de interes
                    filterProperties[i] = {};//Inicializar el objeto para cada elemento del arreglo
                    ids[activeTab].forEach(key=>{
                        if(el[key]._id){
                            el[key] = el[key].Nombre_Empresa;
                        }
                        filterProperties[i][key] = el[key];
                    })
                    return filterProperties;
                });
                console.log(dt);
                let stateData = this.state.data.slice();
                stateData[activeTab] = dt.slice();
                this.setState({data:stateData});
            }else{
                let stateData = this.state.data.slice();
                stateData[activeTab] = [];
                this.setState({data:stateData})
            }
```

Exactamente en esta parte del codigo **if(el[key]._id){**

Comment: podrias explicar que esto `ids[activeTab].forEach`

Comment: Según el error el tipo aparece undefined, ¿has intentando hacer un `console.log()` de ese `_id` que supuesta es undefined? También prueba castearlo como ObjectId.

Comment: `ids[activeTab].forEach` era el error, ahí basicamente definicia la estructura del JSON `this.ids = [['_id','Estado', 'Nombre_Empresa'],[]];` y primero esta colocando el 'Estado'